# file upload to wcf using jquery

Tags: jquery, wcf, file-upload

I have a page where there is a file upload control. I want to send the contents of this file upload control to a WCF service using jquery ( without posting the form ), is that possible?

Comment: By `file upload control` you mean `<input type="file">` or some component that you are using?

Comment: Yes using <input type='file' , ryan there is no sample code I am creating this from scratch .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. I use [jQuery file uploader](http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload) which is a script that automates a lot of it and also adds nice features like the ability to stop a download if the browser supports it.

Examples there should help you get started.